# Authorize .Net DPM Tranasction id

Tags: api, asp.net-mvc-4, authorize.net

How to get an transaction id in authorize net and response while redirecting from this [URL](https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll) ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [ask] and [mcve]. And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922).

Answer (score 0):

The transaction id from a successful transaction would be in a variable by the name of x_trans_id, which would be posted to your specified x_relay_url.